# Difference between Semaphore initialized with 1 and 0

Tags: java, semaphore, java.util.concurrent

Please tell what is difference between a `Semaphore` initialized with 1 and Vs. intialized zero, as below:

```
public static Semaphore semOne = new Semaphore(1);
```

and

```
public static Semaphore semZero = new Semaphore(0);
```

Comment: It specifies the *permits*. check [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html)

Comment: @TheLostMind javadocs mention a negative permits, but not zero

Comment: It behaves same as in the case if the permits is negative. We need to call release() on semaphore before calling acquire().

Comment: how many threads will be able to acquire once the semzero is released? is it 1? basically what's no of permits allowed by semzero

Comment: Is it then possible to keep calling release() on the Semaphore (SemZero) and make it be able to behave like having more permits?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The argument to the Semaphore instance is the number of "permits" that are available. It can be any integer, not just 0 or 1.

For `semZero` all `acquire()` calls will block and `tryAcquire()` calls will return false, until you do a `release()`

For `semOne` the first `acquire()` calls will succeed and the rest will block until the first one releases.

The class is well documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html).

> Parameters: permits - the initial number of permits available. This
>   value may be negative, in which case releases must occur before any
>   acquires will be granted.

Comment: how many threads will be able to acquire once the semzero is released? is it 1? basically what's no of permits allowed by semzero

Comment: @ETHER none. If it's 0 then you need to release it 1st before anyone can acquire it.

Comment: Is it possible to keep calling release() on the Semaphore (SemZero) multiple times before an acquire can be invoked?

Answer (score 10):

the constructor parameter `permits` (initial semaphore counter) is the number of calls to `Semaphore.aquire()` that can be made before the counter (permits) is zero, and the `acquire()`blocks.

**1** is a normal value, to ensure that only one thread passes the acquire.

```
semaphore.acquire();
try {
    // Critical region
    ...
} finally {
    semaphore.release();
}
```

For a usage of **0** see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25501188/how-to-return-value-from-anonymous-class/25501495#25501495).

**Semaphore** is a low-level mechanism for concurrency: a counter when reaching zero blocking thread execution. It stems from [Dijkstra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edsger_W._Dijkstra) where the binary semaphore (0, 1) is a metaphore for a railway semaphore saying pass (halt when 0, pass --permits) and at the end of the protected track does a release (++permits).

Comment: how many threads will be able to acquire once the semzero is released? is it 1? basically what's no of permits allowed by semzero

Comment: @developer Consider  `... acquire(); [Critical Section] release(); ...` will allow exactly one other `acquire()` (called after the first acquire) to pass. In Computer Science the Dutch Dijkstra used the train analogy: semaphore, P=passeren=try-pass/acquire, V=vrij maken=release.

Answer (score 7):

When I first read the documentation of the Semaphore I also misinterpreted the explanation. The main point I missed was the part of '...INITIAL number of permits...'. Somehow I though this would be the number of permits which would be available as a MAXIMUM, but that is NOT the case. In the end the semaphore just counts up from any number but only starts the enable waiting threads (which use the acquire) when the semaphore permits are above 1.

A simple piece of (non threading) code shows this too:

```
@Test
public void testNegativeSemaphore()
{
    Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(-2);

    assertEquals(-2, semaphore.availablePermits());
    semaphore.release();
    assertEquals(-1, semaphore.availablePermits());
    semaphore.release();
    assertEquals(0, semaphore.availablePermits());
    semaphore.release();
    assertEquals(1, semaphore.availablePermits());
}
```

As the code shows, the available permits increase upon each release, only to allow other threads to acquire a permit once the value reaches 1 or above.

NOTE that from there on the availablePermits cannot become negative by using the aqcuire because if there are 0 permits the whole point of the semaphore is to wait for a permit to become available again!